# Creating a custom DistributedMapCacheClient controller service for stock nifi processor

Tags: java, service, controller, apache-nifi

I can't seem to create a custom DistributedMapCacheClientService (named TestDistributedMapCacheClientService) for stock nifi processors (such as Wait and PutDistributedMapCache) to use. I was able to get my custom service to be seen by Wait and PutDistributedMapCache but the processors cannot be started because nifi says my nar "is not compatible with AtomicDistributedMapCacheClient".

```
public class TestDistributedMapCacheClientService extends AbstractControllerService implements AtomicDistributedMapCacheClient<byte[]> {
  :
}
```

[nifi canvas error for Wait processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAgIM.jpg)

[nifi canvas error for PutDistributedMapCache processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OWGN.jpg)

[TestDistributedMapCacheClientService is selectable from properties dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7xPH.png)

[TestDistributedMapCacheClientService is selectable from properties dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkgIc.png)

I don't have any problems if i select any of nifi's DistributedMapCacheClientServices (like CouchbaseMapCacheClient or RedisDistributedMapCacheClient) just my custom one. I appreciate any help.

Here is my project setup and their dependencies:

- my-nifi-services-bundle

  - my-nifi-services

    - my-nifi-services-api
    - nifi-api (provided)
    - nifi-standard-services (pom)
    - nifi-distributed-cache-client-service-api (provided)
  - my-nifi-services-api

    - nifi-api (provided)
    - nifi-distributed-cache-client-service-api (provided)
  - my-nifi-services-nar

    - nifi-standard-services-api-nar (nar)
    - my-nifi-services
  - my-nifi-services-api-nar

    - my-nifi-services-api
    - nifi-standard-services-api-nar (nar)

[image]

Comment: have you defined `META-INF/services/org.apache.nifi.controller.ControllerService` ?  could you show the list of all nifi libraries included into NAR ?

Comment: @daggett yes i did that. Otherwise my test controller service wouldn't even be available to select from on the canvas.

Comment: And nifi libs in nar?

Comment: @dagget. Yes. It's all there. It appears I'm not the only one having this problem, though this thread is rather old. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/NiFi-Custom-Controller-Service-Implementation-Setup/td-p/218851

Comment: you should not have any internal nifi libraries inside NAR.

Comment: @dagget. Sorry I may have misunderstood you. Here's exactly what's in my two nar pom.xml:

nifi-services-api-nar:
            <artifactId>nifi-services-api</artifactId>
            <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>

nifi-services-nar:
            <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
            <artifactId>nifi-services</artifactId>

Comment: could you please open your `xxx.nar` artifact as zip archive, open `\META-INF\bundled-dependencies` folder in it. and provide the list of files there in question (not in comment). expected result: you should not have any standard `nifi-yyy-VER.jar` in there except maybe `nifi-utils-VER.jar`.

Comment: @dagget I have updated my question and included an image of contents of both my nars.

Comment: Ok.  the problem that you have native nifi jars in your NAR - so, you are overriding definition of nifi original classes.. for example `nifi-api-1.8.0.jar` should not be inside your NAR.

Comment: @daggett. Your suggestion helped me find the problem. My dependency was against nifi.version 1.8 but my install was 1.92. My nars still contain the nifi-xxx.jars however but all appear to work now. I guess I need to keep my source version in sync with my nifi install version.

Answer (score 0):

> but the processors cannot be started because nifi says my nar "is not compatible with AtomicDistributedMapCacheClient".

There are two potential causes (both might apply):

1. You need to implement `AtomicDistributedMapCacheClient`, not `DistributedMapCacheClient`.
2. You need to synchronize your project dependencies with the version of NiFi you're running (like 1.12.1 to 1.12.1; must be **exact** with these services)

At a minimum, #1 applies because `AtomicDistributedMapCacheClient` is a child interface of `DistributedMapCacheClient`.